# Why does the unsigned int give a negative value in c++?

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

I have two functions add and main as follows.

```
int add(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{   
   unsigned int a,b;
   cout << "Enter a value for a: ";
   cin >> a;
   cout << "Enter a value for b: ";
   cin >> b;
   cout << "a: " << a << "   b: "<<b <<endl;
   cout << "Result is: " << add(a,b) <<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

When I run this program I get the following results:

```
Enter a value for a: -1
Enter a value for b: -2
a: 4294967295   b: 4294967294
Result is: -3
```

Why is the result -3?

Comment: You need to look at the representation of integers (both positive and negative).

Comment: You might return unsigned in a binary operation taking two unsigned , or take two signed and return signed.

Comment: Do you intend to return a signed int or an unsigned int?

Comment: why does bitwise not always give negative value in c++? I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: if x=8, its binary is 1000. when I use ~ it must be 0111. here MSD is 0. so it must be a positive.  Now convert it to decimal format, the 1st complement of 0111 is 1000, and add 1, 1001. its value is 9. but I get negative value (-9).

Answer (score 8):

Because `add` returns an `int` (no `unsigned int`) which cannot represent `4294967295 + 4294967294 = 4294967293` (unsigned integer arithmetic is defined `mod 2^n` with `n = 32` in this case) because the result is too big.

Thus, you have signed integer overflow (or, more precisely, an implicit conversion from a source integer that cannot be represented as `int`) which has an implementation defined result, i.e. any output (that is representable as `int`) would be "correct".

The reason for getting exactly `-3` is that the result is `2^32 - 3` and that gets converted to `-3` on your system. But still, note that any result would be equally legal.

Comment: does it add (-1 and -2) or add ( 4294967295   and 4294967294)?

Comment: @SharthrakNiroshan It adds the unsigned numbers (mod 2^32).

Comment: @SharthrakNiroshan, it does add 4294967295 and 4294967294, but then your `add()` function returns `int`, not `unsigned int`, so the result gets converted to signed int.

Answer (score 1):

```
int add(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

The expression `a+b` adds two operands of type `unsigned int`, yielding an `unsigned int` result. Unsigned addition, strictly speaking, does not "overflow"; rather than result is reduced modulo MAX + 1, where MAX is the maximum value of the unsigned type. In this case, assuming 32-bit `unsigned int`, the result of adding `4294967295 + 4294967294` is well defined: it's `4294967293`, or 2<sup>32</sup>-3.

Since `add` is defined to return an `int` result, the `unsigned` value is implicitly converted from `unsigned int` to `int`. Unlike an arithmetic overflow, an unsigned-to-signed conversion that can't be represented in the target type yields an *implementation-defined* result. On a typical implementation, such a conversion (where the source and target have the same size) will reinterpret the representation, yielding `-3`. Other results are possible, depending on the implementation, but not particularly likely.

As for why `a` and `b` were set to those values in the first place, apparently that's how `cin >> a` behaves when `a` is an unsigned value and the input is negative. I'm not sure whether that behavior is defined by the language, implementation-defined, or undefined. In any case, once you have those values, the result returned by `add` follows as described above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to return an unsigned int then you need to add unsigned to your function declaration. If you changed your return type to an unsigned int
and you use the values -1 & -2 then this will be your output:

```
a: 4294967295 b: 4294967294
Result: 4294967293
```

unsigned int ranges from [0, 4294967295] provided an unsigned int is 4bytes in size on your local machine. When you input -1 for an unsigned int you have buffer overflow and what happens here is the compiler will set -1 to be the largest possible valid number in an unsigned int. When you pass -2 into your function the same thing happens but you are being index back to the second largest value. With unsigned int there is no "sign" for negatives stored. If you take the largest possible value of an unsigned as stated above by (a) and add 1 it will give you a value of 0. These values are passed into the function, and the function creates 2 stack variables of local scope within this function.
So now you have a copy of a & b on the stack and a has a value of unsigned int max size and b has a value of unsigned int max size - 1. Now you are performing an addition on these two values which exceeds the max value size of an unsigned int and wrapping occurs in the opposite direction. So if the index value starts at .....95 and you add 1 this gives you 0 for the last digit, so if you take the second value which is max value - 1 : .....94 subtract one from it because we already reached 0 now we are in the positive direction. This will give you a result of ......93 which the function is returning if your return type is unsigned int.

This same concept applies if your return type is int, however what happens here
is this: The addition of the two unsigned values are the same result giving you
.....93 then the compiler will implicitly cast this to an int. Well here the range value for a signed int is -2147483648 to 2147483647 - one bit is used to store the (signed value) but it also depends on if two's compliment is being used etc.

The compiler here is smart enough to know that the signed int has a range of these values but the wrapping still occurs. What happens when we store 4294967293 into a singed int? Well the max value of int in the positive is 2147483647 so if we subtract the two (4294967293 - 2147483647) we would get 2147483646 left over. At this point does this value fit in the range of a signed int max value? It does however because of the implicit casting being done from an unsigned to a signed value we have 2 bits to account for, the signed itself and the wrapping value meaning max_value + 1 = 0 to account for, except this doesn't happen with signed values when you add 1 to max_value you get the largest possible -max_value.

For the unsigned values:

```
- ...95  = -1
- ...94  = -2
- ...93  = -3
```

With signed values the negative is preserved in its own bit, or if twos compliment is used etc., pending on the definitions to a signed int within the compiler. Here the compiler recognizes this unsigned value as being negative even though negative values are not stored in an unsigned for the sign is not preserved. So when it explicitly casts from an unsigned to signed one bit is used to store the signed value then the calculations are done and the wrapping occurs from a buffer overflow. So as we subtracted the actual unsigned value that would represent -3 : 4294967293 with the max+ value for a signed int 2147483647 we got the value 2147483646 now with signed ints if you add 1 to the max value it does not give you 0 like an unsigned does, it will give you the largest -signed value which for a 4byte int is -2147483648, since this does fit in the max+ value and the compiler knows that this is supposed to be a negative value if we add our remainder by the -max_value for a signed int :  2147483646  + (-2147483648) this will give us -2, but because of the fact that the wrapping with int is different we have to subtract 1 from this -2 - 1 = -3.

Answer (score -1):

When it converts from an unsigned int to an int, the number is over what a signed integer can hold. This causes it to overflow as a negative value.

If you change the return value to an unsigned integer, your problem should be solved.